Outlook with multiple accounts each with their own item list and reading pane
I have my main outlook account me@outlook.com and then an imap account foo@bar.com. Clicking on a folder in either account gets loaded into a shared Item List (emails) and Reading Pane (selected email) ... in order to avoid confusion I'd like to be able to split the Outlook window horizontally. One account would be above the line and the other below, so that each email account has it's own item list and reading pane. Is this possible? Using latest version of Outlook Classic.

Legend
4 : Item List
5 : Reading Pane

A simpler solution (requriing zero VBA/COM!) would be to define a separate Outlook Profile (this is done under Start > Control Panel > Mail/Outlook) then open two separate instances of outlook.exe: one using the first profile (with your MSA) and the second instance using a secondary profile which contains only your IMAP account.

This does not sound like a programming question. It really belongs at SuperUser.

@Dai - outlook is a singleton: only once instance of outlook.exe is running per login.

@DmitryStreblechenko Perhaps use runas to work-around that?

Then you'd need to create separate profiles for both users then. If you have two stores in a profile, just open two separate windows in Outlook - right click on the Inbox of the second mailbox and select "Open in New Window".
